# Taking a picture with voice command on Android

Tags: android, camera, voice-command

I'm looking for a program that can take picture with voice command whenever I say "take a picture" (or some similar command) on Android. Free is better.

I am aware of the [Google Now application for Android](http://bgr.com/2014/03/20/google-now-voice-commands-for-camera/), which can launch the camera application through a voice command but it's a bit tedious to have to 1) launch Google Now 2) click on the camera application's button to take a picture.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever it comes to automation, the first thing I consider is checking **[Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/)** – which is *the* automation app for Android. And allright, it supports this.

A little background in case you've never heard of this app (which I doubt): *Tasker* uses "profiles", which consist of two parts: Conditions, and Tasks. So you define tasks to be processed whenever a certain condition matches. Your action can be found in the [Tasker UserGuide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/ah_index.html) and is named "Take Photo". Your condition should be a voice command. While *Tasker* has support for that built-in, you'd get much more flexibility using the [AutoVoice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autovoice) addon, which also offers a "continuous" mode (aka "Always Listen") if you wish. So some example profiles (pseudo-code, just the raw idea – you will need to finetune them):

#### Trigger VoiceDetection

- **Condition:** e.g. "shake device two times left to right"
- **Action:** Start AutoVoice in listening mode

This profile you need to setup only once, and then use it with many defined voice commands, like taking a photo:

#### Taking a photo

- **Condition:** AutoVoice detected your "take a photo" command
- **Task:** "Take Photo"

#### What you need

- [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (obviously)
- the [AutoVoice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autovoice) addon (optional, but highly recommended)
- an Android device connected to the Internet (Google's voice detection aka "speak to text" is used)

[image: Tasker] [image: AutoVoice]
<sup>*Tasker* profiles view, *AutoVoice* in action (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

#### Further resources

I recommend you taking a look in my [Collection of Tasker Resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker) where you can also find several tutorials which help you get started with *Tasker* in general, and also specifically *AutoVoice*.