# Open source voice-triggered camera

Tags: android, open-source, camera, voice-command

When taking a group picture, there's always one person who presses the shutter and thus is not on the picture, which is a bit sad.

Another option is to use the timer, but it is not very convenient and makes people wait.

**QUESTION:** Is there an app that would trigger the shutter when I say *"Cheese!"* or another magic word?

Requirement:

- Open source (unlike [Tasker](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11773/140))

Bonus:

- Integrates with the default camera app, is not a separate app
- Configurable magic word

*([same question without the open-source requirement](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11768/taking-a-picture-with-voice-command-on-android))*